# Can't run SWT app in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I was following the tutorial that came in the Eclipse editor (click `Help -> Welcome -> Tutorials`). I worked through all the steps which were:

> This cheat sheet shows you how to create a "Hello World" application
>   that uses the Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT). The application will
>   simply display an empty window to the user. If you need help at any
>   step, click the (?) to the right. Let's get started!
>
> If you're not already in the Java perspective, in the main menu select
>   Window > Open Perspective > Java or click on the "Click to Perform"
>   link below.
>
> Open the Import wizard from the main menu via File > Import..., and
>   select Plug-in Development > Plug-ins and Fragments. Click Next. On
>   the Import Plug-ins and Fragments page, select  Import from: The
>   active target platform. Plug-ins and Fragments to import: Select from
>   all plug-ins and fragments found at specified location. Import As:
>   Projects with source folders. Click Next. On the Selection page, Add
>   org.eclipse.swt.{platform}.{os}.{arch} (for example:
>   org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86 for win32) to Plug-ins and Fragments
>   to Import: list. Click Finish. This will create the
>   org.eclipse.swt.{platform}.{os}.{arch} project which we will need to
>   compile and run the application.
>
> Now we need a project to store our own source code. In the main
>   toolbar, click on the New Java Project button, or click on the link
>   below. Enter HelloWorldSWT for the project name, then click Finish.
>
> Since our project requires SWT, we need to specify this in the project
>   properties. Right-click on the project and select Properties. In the
>   Java Build Path page open the Projects tab, add the
>   org.eclipse.swt.{platform}.{os}.{arch} project, then click OK.
>
> The next step is to create a new class. In the main toolbar, click on
>   the New Java Class button (or the link below). If not already
>   specified, select HelloWorldSWT/src as the source folder. Enter
>   HelloWorldSWT for the class name and select the checkbox to create the
>   main() method, then click Finish. The Java editor will automatically
>   open showing your new class.
>
> In the Java editor, enter the following Java code in the main()
>   method: Display display = new Display(); Shell shell = new
>   Shell(display); shell.setText("Hello world!"); shell.open(); while
>   (!shell.isDisposed()) { if (!display.readAndDispatch())
>   display.sleep(); } display.dispose(); You will get compile errors.
>   Right click in the Java editor and select Source > Organize Imports,
>   then save your changes.
>
> To run your application, right-click on your class in the Package
>   Explorer and select Run As > Java Application. A new empty window
>   should appear with the title "Hello world!". Congratulations! You have
>   successfully created a Hello World SWT application!

And here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

But when I tried to run the program, instead of displaying a blank screen as expected, it dumped this in the terminal:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
no swt-cocoa-4233 in java.library.path
no swt-cocoa in java.library.path
Can't load library: /Users/devenkelling/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4233.jnilib
Can't load library: /Users/devenkelling/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa.jnilib

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:101)
at HelloWorldSWT.main(HelloWorldSWT.java:11
```

I'm using an x64 system with the 64-bit Eclipse installed and both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Java (I think). Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I hope this helped. It really confused me in the beginning.

Comment: Did you import the SWT project into workspace as it suggested in the tutorials?

Comment: @RomanC Yes, but it didn't work **:(** Probably due to discrepancies between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, Java and Eclipse.

Comment: There's no discrepancies but mistake to choose corresponding platform.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Source:** [Eclipse Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/908129/)

This worked for me:

- <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on your your project folder `HelloWorldSWT`;
- Go to `Properties` -> Left Sidebar `Java Build Path` -> Tab `Projects`;
- Expand the `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64` folder by clicking on the arrow left to it;
- Select `Native library location` and click `Edit`;
- Click the `Workspace` button and select `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64`;
- Click `OK` a couple of times;

And you're done! Hope this helped.